# Laravel App make function call is failing silently

Tags: php, laravel

Simply as the title, very, very strange behaviour. Code that has not changed in months suddenly is dying silently. No errors in Laravel logs, nginx logs, docker logs, php fpm logs, ubuntu logs...

I tried running via tinker the follwing line:

```
 $productImportService = \App::make(\App\Services\Local\Product\Peer\ProductImportService::class);
```

And it just hangs... Any App::make call hangs to any class.

I have dumped composer auto-load, cleared all caches. I've even killed all the containers completey and re-built from scrath, restarted machine etc etc...

I have absolutely no idea what can cause this behaviour, anyone got any ideas that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: use resolve or app helpers. see if it behaves the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered the issue.. I had created a DI (dependancy injection) infinite loop.

This will cause Laravel to just hang and die silently. Case closed.